# How to search partial text in mongoose and nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongoose

please I was able to retrieve the users' number (part one) using node.js and mongoose. Below is my code:

```
        const contacts = req.body.contacts;
        if ( contacts )
        {
            const numbers = contacts.split( "," );
            if ( numbers.length !== 0 )
            {
                let users = [];

                for ( let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++ )
                {
                    const user = await User.findOne( { completeNumber: { $regex: numbers[ i ], $options: "i" } } );
                    if ( user )
                    {
                        users.push( user );
                    }
                }
                res.json( { "users": users } );
            } else
            {
                res.status( 200 ).json( { message: "No contacts are empty" } );
            }
        } else
        {
            res.status( 404 ).json( { error: { message: "No contacts provided" } } );
        }
```

I do not think using for loop to query each user according to the number is a good idea or practice because it may contribute to slow performance so I hope you may have a better way to do that. I need your guide. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by modifying the regex pattern.

```
        if ( contacts )
        {
            const joinedNumbers = contacts.split( "," ).join('|');
            User.find( { completeNumber: { $regex: joinedNumbers, $options: "i" } }, "name isoCode number completeNumber", ( err, users ) =>
            {
                if ( err )
                {
                    res.status( 404 ).json( { error: err } );
                } else
                {
                    res.json( users );
                }
            } );
        } else
        {
            res.status( 400 ).json( { error: { message: "No contacts" } } );
        }
```